# I want to optimize the request for images on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want optimize my website page request https://www.technoswift.in/
Here I get 21  images with 21 request

is it possible to get the 21 images in single array in php format and call it when required and then browser consider it as only one request

[image]

so I get the images in single array but what happen when echo it with  tag src attribute

Like

```
<img src"<?php echo img[0]; ?>" />
<img src"<?php echo img[1]; ?>" />
<img src"<?php echo img[2]; ?>" />
<img src"<?php echo img[3]; ?>" />
.
.
.
<img src"<?php echo img[20]; ?>" />
```

Here is solution :
I converted image into base64 and put in src attribute it works now http request count is decrease

Comment: `is it possible to get the 21 images in single array in php format and call it when required and then browser consider it as only one request` No, as then you'd be making 22 requests; 1 to get the AJAX then still 21 to get all the images. It shouldn't be an issue anyway, so long as you're optimised the images properly, as they will be read from cache after the first request - as your screenshot shows. Most of the requests took 0ms as they came from the cache

Comment: You could return the 21 images' data as strings in a single request but that's a lot of needless complexity for very very small amount of request overhead saved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "optimize" you can use [Squoosh](https://squoosh.app) to compress your images and improve the cache in your webserver configuration.
For the dark magic, if you want to load only visible 
You can try something like (code not tested, typed directly on the post):

```
var imgs = <?=json_encode($img)?>;
window.onresize = 
window.onscroll =
window.onload = () => {
    let noloads = document.querySelectorAll("img.no-load");
    for (let im in nolaods) {
        if (im.offsetTop < document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) {
            im.src = imgs[im.dataset.id];
            im.classList.remove("no-load");
        }
    }

};
```

```
<img class="no-load" data-id="2" /> <!-- no default src -->
```

Comment: But my concern is that reducing the request count @Mars073

Comment: If the person doesn't see the images, he doesn't make the requests so it makes less requests, if you want to have less requests the only solution is to gather the images in sprites and cut them with css or canvas

Comment: I converted image into base64 and put in src attribute it works now http request count is decrease @mars073

Comment: see above @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @John Conde I converted image into base64 and put in src attribute it works now http request count is decrease